# Cumulative table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: one with a Forecast by month a SKU and the other one with the orders received.

Forecast

| Year | Month | SKU | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | A01 | 100 |
| 2021 | 2 | A01 | 300 |
| 2021 | 3 | A01 | 500 |

Orders

| Date | SKU | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A01 | 40 |
| 2021-01-03 | A01 | 200 |
| 2021-01-28 | A01 | 325 |

What I want to do is a table that determines from which Forecast your are consuming every time a new orders comes. The table that I want to construct in SQL should look like this:

| Date | SKU | Total Order | Fraction Order | Total Forecast | Initial | Remaining | Fcast_Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A01 | 40 | 40 | 100 | 100 | 60 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | A01 | 200 | 60 | 100 | 60 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | A01 | 200 | 140 | 300 | 300 | 160 | 2 |
| 2021-01-28 | A01 | 325 | 160 | 300 | 160 | 0 | 2 |
| 2021-01-28 | A01 | 325 | 165 | 500 | 500 | 335 | 3 |

The column fraction order is a split of the order when the Remaining Forecast is less than the order. The orders can arrive before or after the Forecast Year and Month, therefore the dates cannot be joined, but the Forecast has to be consumed in the logical order (January should go first, than Feb and so on).

I think this can be solved doing a while loop in SQL but I haven't figured it out. Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of stripping the `forecast` and `orders` tables down to the minimum needed to get the gist of the problem:

[image: Forecast and Orders tables]

Here's a while loop that solves the problem as I understand it:

```
DECLARE @xactions TABLE (
    XactNum int IDENTITY(1,1),
    TakeAmount int,
    ForecastRemaining int,
    OrderRemaining int,
    ForecastMonth int, OrderNum int
);

DECLARE @forecastMonth int;
DECLARE @forecastRemaining int;
DECLARE @orderNum int;
DECLARE @orderRemaining int;
DECLARE @takeAmount int;

SELECT @forecastMonth = 1, @forecastRemaining = Qty FROM forecast WHERE [Month] = 1;

SELECT @orderNum = 1, @orderRemaining = Qty FROM orders WHERE OrderNum = 1;

WHILE @orderRemaining > 0
BEGIN
    SET @takeAmount = iif(@forecastRemaining > @orderRemaining, @orderRemaining, @forecastRemaining);

    SET @forecastRemaining -= @takeAmount;
    SET @orderRemaining -= @takeAmount;

    INSERT @xactions ( TakeAmount, ForecastMonth, OrderNum, ForecastRemaining, OrderRemaining )
    VALUES ( @takeAmount, @forecastMonth, @orderNum, @forecastRemaining, @orderRemaining );

    IF @forecastRemaining = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @forecastMonth += 1;
        SET @forecastRemaining = ISNULL((SELECT Qty FROM forecast WHERE [Month] = @forecastMonth), 0);
    END

    IF @orderRemaining = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @orderNum += 1;
        SET @orderRemaining = ISNULL((SELECT Qty FROM orders WHERE OrderNum = @orderNum), 0);
    END
END

SELECT * FROM @xactions ORDER BY XactNum;
```